# Is SGX enabled on my Surface 4 pro?

Tags: x86, intel

As Intel already confessed, the first charges of Skylake processors did not have SGX enabled.
CPUID seems not to indicate this.
So, my question is, how can I know if my recently bought MS Surface pro with I5 Skylake processor has SGX enabled or not?

Answer (score 3):

Currently Intel SGX mode is not enabled in Surface Pro 4, but the CPU in Surface Pro 4 supports Intel SGX.
I'm using i7 model, I coded simple program using enclave APIs.
In enclave APIs, there is a API to check whether your system supports Intel SGX or not, which name is IsEnclaveTypeSupported.

It returns FALSE on my system, but AIDA64 indicated that my system supports Intel SGX mode.

So What we can only do now is that just wait for releasing new UEFI firmware from MS later.

Answer (score 2):

If `smx` is set - SGX global enable is supported. It can be checked by calling `cpuid` assembly instruction with EAX=1:

```
CPUID.1:ECX.[bit6]
```

You can use [this link](https://gist.github.com/ayeks/5ebefd33321cfd245a17) as reference for writing C program to check if SGX is enabled and check also all the SGX related parameters.

Comment: cpuid with eax:07 says sgx:1  but cpuid leaf 12h is all zero. What does this mean?

Comment: @Cryptostasis If I remember correctly, it means that the CPU supports SGX but the bios probably is old and doesn't know how to configure the system to make SGX available for usage.

Answer (score 2):

There's some code available [here](https://gist.github.com/ayeks/5ebefd33321cfd245a17) that prints out the cpuid information to tell you whether or not SGX is enabled:

Example output:

```
Extended feature bits (EAX=07H, ECX=0H) 
eax: 0 ebx: 29c6fbf ecx: 0 edx: 0
sgx available: 1
```

For information on what the register values mean, see section 1.7 of the [manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/48/88/329298-002.pdf)